# Memory Usage: M1/M2 Macs, vs Intel

Tags: memory, apple-silicon

Wondering if M1/2 Macs use memory more efficiently than Intel Macs? Do I need to upgrade RAM to 16MB or is 8MB enough? My main memory hogs would be FotoMagico or iMovie, Photos to present slideshows or create home movies.
Don't need to run many apps at once.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't buy anything with only 8GB these days. The smallest Mac we have in the building is a 16GB M1 iMac & that's really easy to choke. As to whether they're more efficient, I haven't a clue - they do move memory around to/from swap faster than an older Mac… but they can still choke.

Answer (score 4):

8 GB is not enough for serious use nowadays, I easily use 14 GB on my M1 mini by doing just simple stuff (and not closing any applications). The RAM on the M1/M2s can't be expanded by the user anyway, so go for the maximum you can get/afford.

Comment: Anecdotally - mine's using about 33GB right now [of 64], not doing much at all. Whatever you have, the system will find a use for it ;))